# Can I get a larger Windows 7 Remote Desktop screen than the real screen on the machine?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have two Windows 7 machines:

A) Has four 1920x1200 displays as the desktop. Windows sees it as two 3840x1200 displays.

B) Has a single 1920x1200 display

When I am using A), I'd like to RDP to B) but give B) a full 3840x2400 desktop and not just scale the screen.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The possible size of your RDP session screen size is always determined by the video capabilities *connecting* computer, not by the machine you are accessing remotely.

An RDP session uses a virtual video driver on the host computer which is completely independent from any actual connected displays. In fact, if this weren't so it wouldn't be possible to remote into a computer that didn't have a display connected at all.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my last video driver update fixed this issue.
When I RDP'd to the system, I could set the "use all my monitors" option, and it worked!